# Can i move the ellipse to centerstart position ? Giving alignment modifier to the box or its children hasn't helped. Am i missing a parameter?

Tags: kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen, box

This is my snippet for the splashscreen function animation included.I'm kind of new to kotlin.Is there a problem with the animation part?

```
        @Composable
        fun SplashScreen(navController: NavController) {
    
            val scale = remember {
                androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable(0f)
            }
    
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                scale.animateTo(
                    targetValue = 0.7f,
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 800,
                        easing = {
                            OvershootInterpolator(4f).getInterpolation(it)
                        })
                )
                delay(1500L)
                navController.navigate("main_screen") {
                    popUpTo("splash_screen") {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

The image- ellipse is displayed at the  center I want it at the centerstart position . Align Modifiers haven't helped.

```
           Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Red)
              
            )
            { 
                 
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_ellipse),
                    contentDescription = " ",
                    modifier = Modifier
    
                        .scale(scale.value).padding(10.dp).align(alignment = Alignment.CenterStart),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    
                    alpha = 1F
                )
    
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 550.dp).align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
                    text = "Hello",
                    color = Color.Yellow,
                    fontSize = 35.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
    
    
                )
    
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
      
    }
```

}

Comment: Maybe your image takes whole width? Try adding `Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f)` to check it.

Comment: thank you but it didn't work the image got cropped in half.

Comment: It should be cropped, but did it moved to `CenterStart`? If so, just add `ContentScale.Fit` instead of `ContentScale.Crop`

Comment: Thanks ! It did move but there's bit of a margin from centerstart left still

Comment: Most probably your image has transparent padding. Open it in any image editor and crop it